# Matching hrefs within String using Scala

Tags: regex, scala

Using this regex `(<a[^>]+>.+?<\\/a>)` I'm attempting to print the matching links.

So `t1,t2,t3` should be printed but nothing is printed :

```
val str = "tester<a href=\"t1\">this is just test text<a href=\"t2\">\\r\\t\\s<a href=\"t3\">"
val re = "(<a[^>]+>.+?<\\/a>)".r
for (p <- re findAllIn str) p match {
  case re(b) => print(b)
}
```

Is the regex or how the regex is implemented incorrect ?

Update :

Using accepted answer this will download all valid hrefs (begin with 'http') from a url, in this case `https://news.ycombinator.com/`:

```
import scala.io.Source
import org.jsoup.Jsoup
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

object Main extends App {

  val hrefs = getHrefsFromPage("https://news.ycombinator.com/");

  hrefs.foreach(e => println(e))

  def getHrefsFromPage(url: String): List[(String, String)] = {

    val doc = Jsoup.parse(Source.fromURL(url).mkString)
    val aTags = doc.select("a").iterator.toList
    val ts = (for (t <- aTags) yield (t.attr("href"), t.text))
    val fts = ts.filter(f => f._1.trim.startsWith("http"))

    return fts;
  }

}
```

Comment: Mandatory SO Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 . Read my answer to see an alternate way of parsing html. And Please don't parse html with regex. Html is not a regular language so regex parsing is not reliable (english language as used is finite, hence regular, so we use regex there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Read this SO Answer first please.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Now coming back.

> You need to use a reliable html parser lib to parse html strings, regex won't be enough in most non-trivial cases.

**Regex won't get the job done because**

- It is error prone, *we make mistakes writing regex all the time*, plus you are tge only verifier and maintainer (maintenance nightmare)
- It is *hard to maintain and document*
- It is *hard to test*, you will have to think of all possible test case strings for your regex and then write test cases for it.

**Why an Html parser is better**

- Not error prone, has been *verified by multiple contributors and users*, unlike your regex which only you use and verify
- *Documented* in its own site and javadoc
- Html Parsing *already tested* in the library itself, you can focus on testing your app functionality or business use case.
- *CSS selectors* and DOM structure to select and manipulate the Html. (This is the biggest benefit, you will need css selectors support for any serious html work.)

As a result of this, I would suggest you to use [Jsoup html parser](https://jsoup.org/). Below I describe usage for your case.

First *get the dependency* or just download the jar. Maven dependency as below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

*Next the imports*

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document
```

*Now parsing your html string*

```
val str = "tester<a href=\"t1\">this is just test text<a href=\"t2\">\\r\\t\\s<a href=\"t3\">"
val doc = Jsoup.parse(str)
```

What this gives:

```
doc: org.jsoup.nodes.Document =
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  tester
  <a href="t1">this is just test text</a>
  <a href="t2">\r\t\s</a>
  <a href="t3"></a>
 </body>
</html>
```

Notice the full structure generated with cleaned tags from your string.

*Getting all `<a>` tags*

```
val aTags = doc.select("a")
```

Result:

```
aTags: org.jsoup.select.Elements =
<a href="t1">this is just test text</a>
<a href="t2">\r\t\s</a>
<a href="t3"></a>
```

*Getting all `<a>` tag string representation*

```
val aTagsString = aTags.toString
```

Result:

```
aTagsString: String =
<a href="t1">this is just test text</a>
<a href="t2">\r\t\s</a>
<a href="t3"></a>
```

*Getting first or 0th `<a>` tag*

```
val firstATag = doc.select("a").get(0)
```

Result:

```
firstATag: org.jsoup.nodes.Element = <a href="t1">this is just test text</a>
```

*Getting string representation of first `<a>` tag*

```
val firstATagString = firstATag.toString
```

Result:

```
firstATagString: String = <a href="t1">this is just test text</a>
```

*Getting inner text of firstATag (0th `<a>` tag)*

```
val firstATagInnerText = firstATag.text
```

Result:

```
firstATagInnerText: String = this is just test text
```

Notice: even though your  tags were not closed this parser worked fine. While your regex implementation failed this edge case.

Comment: thanks for detail, ive posted my solution to question based on your code.

Comment: @blue-sky : Glad that I could help. :)